# Algebra. Multiplying binomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus

could you please explain, share link about multiplication binomials issue.

For example 
$(2a + 7)(a - 5)$

As i know, need to do next

1. $2a \times a; 2a \times -5$
2. $7 \times a; 7 \times -5$

But the answer is $2a^2 - 3a -35$

$3a$ ? what is going on ?

Comment: You have to add the four terms you have found. Two of the terms were $2a\times(-5)=-10a$ and $7a$; they sum to $-3a$.

Comment: What's the problem?  Line $1$ gives $2a^2-10a$.   Line $2$ gives $7a-35$.  Combining we get $2a^2-10a+7a-35=2a^2-3a-35$.  Note that $-10a+7a=-3a$.

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

1. $2a\times a=2a^2$ and $2a\times-5=-10a$
2. $7\times a=7a$ and $7\times-5=-35$

Now, add them all up:
$$2a^2-10a+7a-35$$
However, the $-10a+7a$ can be simplified to just $-3a$, which is where that comes from.

Answer (score 0):

It holds that $$(x+y)(z+d)=xz+xd+yz+yd$$

So

$$(2a+7)(a-5)=2a^2-10a+7a-35=2a^2-3a-35$$